# 'vbs' is not recognized as an operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, imagemagick

I'm having a problem with a batch file I've written.  The file works properly on various Win7 machines, but on the few WinXP machines that we have left, the program crashes out when I get to "CALLING" another batch file, titled, "VBS".  VBS is a mathematical batch file that works properly.  Strangely enough, if I create a separate batch file and try to CALL VBS (5+5+5) on WinXP, it will return the proper answer of 15.

Does WinXP just not like the variables in the math equation?  I've stepped through each part of the process to ensure that each variable is being fulfilled, and it is.

Does anybody have any ideas?

I did not post the entire code for the program, as it is over 18,000 lines, but this is the part that is giving me trouble, which is at/towards the beginning of the code.

Thank you.

```
identify -verbose %1 >%1.txt

:CREATE_DIR
if exist "\\celsus\customer artwork\New Artwork\%group%\%new_name%\" (
    GOTO :ADVANCED_METRICS
)   ELSE (
    mkdir "\\celsus\customer artwork\New Artwork\%group%\%new_name%\"
    copy "File Processing.bat" "\\celsus\customer artwork\New Artwork\%group%\%new_name%\"
    copy "Create Report.bat" "\\celsus\customer artwork\New Artwork\%group%\%new_name%\"
    goto ADVANCED_METRICS
```

)

```
:ADVANCED_METRICS
FINDSTR "\<Format:" %1.txt >Format.txt
for /f "tokens=2" %%A in (
Format.txt
) do set Format=%%A

FINDSTR "\<Geometry:" %1.txt >Geometry.txt
for /f "tokens=2 delims=+ " %%A in (
Geometry.txt
) do set Geometry=%%A

FINDSTR "\<Print size:" %1.txt >pSize.txt
for /f "tokens=3" %%A in (
pSize.txt
) do set pSize=%%A

FINDSTR "x" pSize.txt >pSizeW.txt
for /f "tokens=3 delims=x " %%A in (
pSizeW.txt
) do set Width=%%A

FINDSTR "\<Print size:" %1.txt >pSize.txt
for /f "tokens=2 delims=x" %%A in (
pSize.txt
) do set Height=%%A

FINDSTR "\<Resolution:" %1.txt >Resolution.txt
for /f "tokens=2 delims=x" %%A in (
Resolution.txt
) do set Resolution=%%A

FINDSTR "\<Colorspace:" %1.txt >Colorspace.txt
for /f "tokens=2" %%A in (
Colorspace.txt
) do set Colorspace=%%A

del %1.txt
del Format.txt
del Geometry.txt
del pSize.txt
del pSizeW.txt
del Resolution.txt
del Colorspace.txt

call vbs ((%Resolution%/300)*%Width%)
set nWidth300=%val%

call vbs ((%Resolution%/600)*%Width%)
set nWidth600=%val%

call vbs ((%Resolution%/300)*%Height%)
set nHeight300=%val%

call vbs ((%Resolution%/600)*%Height%)
set nHeight600=%val%
```

Comment: That error basically means it is not finding the program.  Are all machines configured the same way to run all the batch files.  Where is it located in relation to the main batch file?

Comment: For the sake of my test, it is right next to the batch file on the desktop.  Why would Win7 find the program (same file locations), but WinXP would not?

Comment: Also, when I make a generic script to call the same batch file, in XP, it works fine:

    set /p Resolution="What is the Resolution?: "
    set /p Width="What is the Width?: "

    call vbs ((%Resolution%/300)*%Width%)
    set nWidth300=%val%
    echo %nWidth300%

    pause

Comment: On a problem machine run your scripts like they would be run but at the top of your batch file echo the current directory to the screen. `echo %cd%`

Comment: Okay - I did that in both files.  If I double click on them, the directories are the same.  However, if I drag/drop a file onto the original batch file, the directory changes from c:\documents and setting\username\desktop to c:\documents and settings\username

The program is a drag and drop program.

Comment: So control what directory the batch file should be in.  Assuming the VBS script is in the same directory as the batch file then do this at the top of your script. `PUSHD %~dp0`

Comment: Additionally, I've changed it to set the directory at the top of the script, but it pauses and displays the directory after each "CALL" function... do you know a way to stop that from happening?

Otherwise - setting the directory seems to have helped.

Comment: DISREGARD LAST REMARK... I caught my own mistake this time.  I had added the "echo %cd% to both batch files... and when it was calling VBS, the first command it was catching was the echo %cd% command...

Thanks a bunch for your help.  This seems to have worked

Comment: We did this all in comments... is there any way to vote your answer as the solution?